# How can we plot a vertical line on all subplots using Python seaborn relplot?

Tags: python, seaborn

The Python code to create the plot used is below. This creates subplots based on `"variable"`:

```
s=sb.relplot(x="timestamp",y="value",hue="variable",row="variable",
kind="line",facet_kws=dict(sharey=False),height=0.8, aspect=7,data=e)

plt.axvline(flip_timex)

s.fig.autofmt_xdate()

plt.show()
```

I need to add a vertical line (on a fixed date) on all the subplots generated.

`plt.axvline(flip_timex)` adds a vertical line only on one subplot.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to create the line in all generated plots.

```
grid = seaborn.relplot(...)
for ax in grid.axes.flat:
    ax.axvline(...)
```

Comment: In my example I had to loop slightly different, just as an addition:
`fig, axs = pl.subplots(ncols=2)`
`sns.kdeplot(..., ax=axs[0])`
`sns.kdeplot(..., ax=axs[1])`
`for ax in fig.axes:`
`ax.axvline(...)`